# Write an SQL Query to calculate total purchase amount of each customer

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to calculate the total purchase amount of each customer from the database available online on [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in)

The tables I'm using are:

> Customers
>
> Orders
>
> Products
>
> OrderDetails

My current query gives me the product wise purchase amount for the customer. What I need is the total purchase amount.

```
SELECT c.CustomerID,o.OrderID,(ord.Quantity*p.Price) as 
Total_Amount
from Customers c inner join Orders o
inner join Products p
inner join OrderDetails ord
on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
and o.OrderID = ord.OrderID
and ord.ProductID = p.ProductID;
```

> **My Output:**

[image: Output]

I need the sum for the values with the same order id and customer id.

I tried out group-by and sum but it gives me the overall sum of all the products.

Answer (score 3):

You simply want a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, SUM(ord.Quantity*p.Price) as 
Total_Amount
FROM Customers c inner join Orders o
     on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID join
     OrderDetails ord
     on o.OrderID = ord.OrderID join
     Products p
     on ord.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

Note that this orders the `JOIN`s so the `ON` clauses are interleaved.  This is how `JOIN`s are normally written.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the sum for the values with the same order id and customer id, then you need to group the rows based on both customer id and order id.

```
SELECT c.CustomerID,o.OrderID,SUM(ord.Quantity*p.Price) as Total_Amount
from Customers c inner join Orders o
inner join Products p
inner join OrderDetails ord
on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
and o.OrderID = ord.OrderID
and ord.ProductID = p.ProductID
Group By c.CustomerID,o.OrderID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to achive that & final result will includes the CustomerID, OrderID & calculated Total_Amount for the each group.

```
SELECT 
   cust.CustomerID,
   ord.OrderID,
   SUM(od.Quantity * pro.Price) as Total_Amount

FROM Customers cust, Orders ord, OrderDetails od, Products pro

WHERE
   cust.CustomerID = ord.CustomerID
   AND ord.OrderID = od.OrderID
   AND od.ProductID = pro.ProductID

GROUP BY
   cust.CustomerID,
   ord.OrderID;
```